# Akka - Actor automatic creation by need

Tags: scala, load-balancing, actor, akka

I'm pretty new in Akka and maybe didn't understanded yet some of it concepts well.

I'm trying to find a way to make the system automatically creates new actor instances if mailbox is exceed over some limit. Is it also posible to do it on remote nodes?

Be glad for any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris B has missed the new awesome Resizers for Routers in Akka 2.0-M4:

Docs: http://akka.io/docs/akka/2.0-M4/scala/routing.html#dynamically-resizable-routers
ScalaDocs: http://akka.io/api/akka/2.0-M4/#akka.routing.DefaultResizer

So, yes, you can have that kind of dynamic resizing for Routers.

Comment: Nice! This is the one feature that I felt Akka was missing in order to be truly useful. Will have to give it another try now.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Akka 2.0 milestone 4), this kind of dynamic load-balancing/scaling is not available. New actors can be created dynamically (this is a fundamental tenet of the Actor model), but there is no built-in way to gauge the load of the system and react accordingly.

There are lots of exciting clustering features scheduled for version 2.1, which hopefully will include what you are looking for.

Here is a roadmap for Akka 2.0 and beyond:

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1CMz_MEQA8oPcGw9oaFdq_KYYFB_5qZjsDYYwuXfZhBU&pli=1